# map geocode API gives Null response

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I'm using the below code for getting the geocode response of a particular address,

```
    NSString *address = @"Doha,Qatar";
    NSLog(@"address : %@",address);
    NSString *esc_addr = [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false", esc_addr];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:req];
    NSLog(@"url : %@",url);
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSLog(@"data : %@",data);
    NSError *error=nil;
    id response=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:
                 NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    NSLog(@"The JSON Object: %@ Or Error is: %@", response, error);
```

But the response is always null.

The response,

```
2014-11-27 16:35:48.961 MyProj[15279:254055] address : Doha,Qatar
2014-11-27 16:35:48.961 MyProj[15279:254055] url : http://www.maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Doha,Qatar&sensor=false
2014-11-27 16:35:49.005 MyProj[15279:254055] data : (null)
2014-11-27 16:35:49.008 MyProj[15279:254055] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
```

But when I open the URL in brows it gives output as,

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Doha",
               "short_name" : "Doha",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Doha",
               "short_name" : "Doha",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Qatar",
               "short_name" : "QA",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Doha, Qatar",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 25.4125783,
                  "lng" : 51.6281212
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 25.1954283,
                  "lng" : 51.4307964
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 25.286667,
               "lng" : 51.533333
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 25.4125783,
                  "lng" : 51.6281212
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 25.1954283,
                  "lng" : 51.4307964
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

What will be the reason for null response,

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: I just copy pasted your same code. I am getting the data and response. Check whether the crash is at some other data.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works fine.

Data parameter is not null.It contains the info of the json.

So,maybe you have to check these

1. The version of Google Maps SDK(I use 1.8.0.8950-not the newest)
2. The initialization of GMS Services
3. Your API Key for google maps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions. The `dataWithContentsOfURL:` not working for me sometimes.
So I used the NSURLConnection. Now it working well.

Below is the changes i've done.

```
    NSString *address = @"Doha,Qatar";
    NSLog(@"address : %@",address);
    NSString *esc_addr = [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false", esc_addr];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:req];

    NSData *theData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]
                                            returningResponse:nil
                                                        error:nil];

    NSDictionary *googleResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theData
                                                            options:0
                                                              error:nil];
```